# Does bloom filter library for use in Solidity exist?

Tags: solidity, hash-algorithm

Since there are strict storage and computational limits forced by a VM some operations for enterprise-level contracts are impossible. Is there some Bloom filter implementation available in existing library for use in Solidity? It could be used to optimise some algorithms. I do not feel ready for porting some algorithm myself :(

Comment: Please provide an example of what you claim is impossible.

Comment: Agreed. Need a better example. Ethereum events actually function from bloom filters.

Comment: Looks like the Aldekein is simply looking for a library which implements a bloom filter. There are op-codes for various hashes and Bitwise logic operations so should be possible to implement a [simple she256 based BF](https://gist.github.com/josephkern/2897618)

Comment: @JackWinters is correct, I'm searching for a library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think bloom filter would be useful in contracts as it is prone to bloating attacks.

Malicious user can add to a bloom filter a number of entries specifically prepared to increase number of false positives (by increasing number of `1`-bits in filter).

Comment: Though in a private Ethereum-based blockchain, where you could all but guarantee the safety of the network, such attacks wouldn't be a concern :-)

Comment: It depends! A pre-committed bloom filter could be useful for specific types of whitelist where the contract doesn't mind a certain number of false positives.